# Home blank screen - File failed to include not mentioned anywhere

Tags: magento-1.9

Getting this inclusion error. This seems to cause home to die now. Blank screen and this is the only error I am getting. Was not the case before. Perhaps me dumping all the cache caused this but doubt it. Here is the error:

```
    tail -n 20 prelaunch.domain.com/var/log/system.log
    2017-02-04T18:08:51+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'TCurrencySwitcher.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/local:
 /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/community:/home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/core:/home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php5/lib/pear')  in /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

Seems that it looks for the file TCurrencySwitcher.php in multiple locations, but cannot find it. And that makes two of us. Cannot locate it nor do I see it included anywhere. `grep -rnw 'prelaunch.domain.com/' -e "TCurrencySwitcher.php"` only showed the same error multiple times in the /var/log/system.log.

When I do a 
`grep -rnw 'prelaunch.domain.com/' -e "TCurrencySwitcher" --exclude-dir prelaunch.domain.com/var/log`

I do find some legacy code (done by previous developer) here:

```
prelaunch.domain.com/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/directory/currency.phtml:32:if(!class_exists('TCurrencySwitcher')) {
prelaunch.domain.com/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/directory/currency.phtml:33:  class TCurrencySwitcher {
prelaunch.domain.com/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/directory/currency.phtml:58:              <?php echo TCurrencySwitcher::codeToIcon($_code); ?>
```

That file has

```
if(!class_exists('TCurrencySwitcher')) {
    class TCurrencySwitcher {


        function codeToIcon($_code) {
            if($_code == 'BND') {
                $_code = 'usd';
            }
            return "<i class='fa fa-".strtolower($_code)."'></i>";
        }
    }
}

if($this->getCurrencyCount()>1): ?>
<div class="currency-switcher">
    <label for="select-currency"><?php echo $this->__('Your Currency:') ?></label>
    <ul class="select-currency-list">
    <?php foreach($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name) {
        $currencyClass = $_code;
        if($this->getCurrentCurrencyCode() == $_code) {
        $currencyClass .= " current";
        }
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code); ?>" 
               class="<?php echo $currencyClass; ?>">
                <?php echo TCurrencySwitcher::codeToIcon($_code); ?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php
    }; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php /*
    <select id="select-currency" name="currency" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Your Currency')) ?>" onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
        <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code) ?>"<?php if($_code==$this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $_name ?> - <?php echo $_code ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
     * 
     */ ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But not the specific include.
Any ideas how I can debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code with below in file `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/directory/currency.phtml`,

```
if($this->getCurrencyCount()>1): ?>
<div class="currency-switcher">
    <label for="select-currency"><?php echo $this->__('Your Currency:') ?></label>
    <ul class="select-currency-list">
    <?php foreach($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name) {
        $currencyClass = $_code;
        if($this->getCurrentCurrencyCode() == $_code) {
            $currencyClass .= " current";
        }
        if($_code == 'BND') {
            $_code = 'usd';
        }
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code); ?>" 
               class="<?php echo $currencyClass; ?>">
                <?php echo "<i class='fa fa-".strtolower($_code)."'></i>"; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php
    }; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php /*
    <select id="select-currency" name="currency" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Your Currency')) ?>" onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
        <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code) ?>"<?php if($_code==$this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $_name ?> - <?php echo $_code ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
     * 
     */ ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Yeah, just did, but still no joy. Really odd.

Comment: Whats the error now?

Comment: `2017-02-05T08:27:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1]/home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:768[2]/home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:84[3]/home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:184[4]/home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:365 [5] /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/Mage.php:684
[6] /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/index.php:83
`

Comment: for headers already sent, refer to the answer by Alan http://stackoverflow.com/a/4673609/1409718 with a single update for replace `Mage::log('File: ' . $file);Mage::log('Line: ' . $line);` with `Mage::log('File: ' . $file, null, 'system.log', true); Mage::log('Line: ' . $line, null, 'system.log', true);`

Comment: Had to fix that and another phtml loading on home block wise. That fixed it all in the end.